# How to hydrate an Entity to its object when ordering when a specific computed field?

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I need to get the diff from some integer, I've a column 'number' with value like 1 and -1, then I want to use `SUM()` to compute the difference.

My DQL is:

```
SELECT
    SUM(av.number) AS number_diff, 
    a
FROM
    Articles a
    LEFT JOIN a.numbers av
GROUP BY
    av.article
ORDER BY
    number_diff DESC
```

It's working but I get a result like this :

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => 
        object (Article)
        .... properties
      'vote_diff' => string '850' (length=3)
```

I need to get rid of such structure and get it in this format:

```
array
  0 => 
     object (Article)
        .... properties
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as `number_diff` is a computed column. It's not part of the entity.

So, each row is an array containing both the entity and the computed column, instead of just the entity.